# What is new Errormessage

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

facing this error like for some time now but fixed it from a link in git
https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1642
here is my error snippet from the terminal

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/trie/urban_sniffle/node_modules/esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:857
npm ERR!   const err = new Error(message);
npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     /home/trie/.npm/_logs/2023-06-04T00_28_13_111Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Do you have an old node version?